# make entire div area clickable

Tags: html, css

so stupid question i know but i am going round in circles... I have this bit of html ....

```
<div class="navbtn"> <p><a class="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>Menu</p>
    </div>
```

The class "nav-toggle" refers to a hamburger that sits within the div navbtn with the word menu by the side of it .... I basically want to make the entire area of navbtn clickable as at the moment i can only click on the hamburger icon itself and nothing else.... the css for navbtn and nav-toggle (hamburger) is as follows

```
.nav-toggle { position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 25px; outline: 0; z-index : 9999; display: inline-block;}

.nav-toggle { cursor: pointer;}
.nav-toggle span, .nav-toggle span:before, .nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 5px;
  width: 45px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  outline: 0;
}
.nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px; 
}
.nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
input::-moz-focus-inner { 
  border: 0; 
}
.nav-toggle span, .nav-toggle span:before, .nav-toggle span:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  outline: 0;
}
.nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: 0;
}
.nav-toggle.active span:before, .nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
.nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

And the navbtn div

```
.navbtn {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: auto;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;

}
.navbtn p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 2.4em 0.6em;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color : #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the anchor outside the div?

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="navbtn">
        <i class="nav-toggle"></i>
        <p><span></span>Menu</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Note I've changed the `<a>` that was inside your `<div>` to an `<i>` which is something some font-icon packages will do. I did it because I see that you have CSS that would mess with things if I made it a span.

Comment: exactly what I was thinking :)

Comment: agreed but on this occasion it wont work because i have a jquery script that basically says "onclick" do what it is meant to do ... i actually don't even need the anchor come to think about it ... hmmm

Comment: if you have an onclick then you can attach the onclick to `.navbutton`

Comment: ok so i win the stupid idiot prize of the year , i guess it is just changing my css brain to html brain to jquery brain to having no brain ! thanks for the help guys everyone gets voted up !